# JavaScript in HTML loaded using jQuery not executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have seen other questions on this subject but none of the answers seem to work in my case.

I have an ASP.NET MVC view (let's call it **A**) which loads another view (let's call it **B**) into a `<div>` using AJAX. View **B** has some JavaScript at the bottom which should be executed when it's loaded into view **A**. However, the script is not being executed regardless of whether I load view B using jQuery's `$.load()` or `$.ajax()`.

I read somewhere that scripts are stripped off when additional selectors are applied to filter the loaded HTML, but I am **not** doing that.

Besides, I can see the `<script>` tag and its contents in the page's source afterwards, so I know for sure nothing is stripped off. Curiously, though, not only is the JavaScript inside the `<script>` tag in view **B** not executed but none of the functions or variables defined there are visible to JavaScript in view **A** (i.e. they are all undefined).

Any ideas, anybody?

Comment: Show us some more code, please

Comment: You can use $.getScript if you want to load and execute some javacript code. $.load won't execute code in <script> tags.

Comment: @mguimard: Actually $.load works just fine as long as you don't use selectors to filter HTML and don't make stupid mistakes like I did. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I feel pretty dumb now but the problem was that the script in view **B** was inside `<script type="text/jscript"></script>` instead of `<script type="text/javascript"></script>`. 
As soon as replaced **j***script* with **java***script* things started working.

Big DUH !!!